# Regex, greedy quantifiers multiple capture groups

Tags: python, regex

I would like to capture n words surrounding a word x without whitespaces. I need a capture group for each word. I can achieve this in the following way (here words after x):

```
import regex
n = 2
x = 'beef tomato chicken trump Madonna'
right_word = '\s+(\S+)'
regex_right = r'^\S*{}\s*'.format(n*right_word)
m_right = regex.search(regex_right, x)
print(m_right.groups())
```

so if x = 'beef tomato chicken trump Madonna', n = 2, `regex_right = '^\S*\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*'`, and I get two capture groups containing 'tomato' and 'chicken'. However, if n=5 I capture nothing which is not the behavior I was looking for. For n = 5 I want to capture all words the right of 'beef'.

I have tried using the greedy quantifier

```
regex_right = r'^\S*(\s+\S+){,n}\s*'
```

but I only get a single group (the last word) no matter how many matches I get (furthermore I get the white spaces as well..).

I finally tried using regex.findall but I cannot limit it to n words but have to specify number of characters?

Can anyone help ?

---

Wiktor helped me(see below) thanks. However I have an additional problem

if 
    x = 'beef, tomato, chicken, trump Madonna'
I cannot figure out how to capture without the commas? I do not want groups as 'tomato,'

Comment: Are you looking for [**this** ?](https://regex101.com/r/dMNijJ/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not match all those words with the first approach because the pattern did not match the input string. You need to make the `right_word` pattern *optional* by enclosing it with `(?:...)?`:

```
import re
x = 'beef tomato chicken trump Madonna'
n = 5
right_word = '(?:\s+(\S+))?'
regex_right = r'^\S*{}'.format(n*right_word)
print(regex_right)
m_right = re.search(regex_right, x)
if m_right:
    print(m_right.groups())
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/OSqfRZ).

The second approach will only work with PyPi regex module because Python `re` does not keep repeated captures, once a quantified capturing group matches a substring again within the same match iteration, its value is re-written.

```
>>> right_word = '\s+(\S+)'
>>> n = 5
>>> regex_right = r'^\S*(?:\s+(\S+)){{1,{0}}}'.format(n)
>>> result = [x.captures(1) for x in regex.finditer(regex_right, "beef tomato chicken trump Madonna")]
>>> result
[['tomato', 'chicken', 'trump', 'Madonna']]
>>> print(regex_right)
^\S*(?:\s+(\S+)){1,5}
```

Note that `^\S*(?:\s+(\S+)){1,5}` has a capturing group #1 inside a quantified non-capturing group that is quantified with the `{1,5}` limiting quantifier, and since PyPi regex keeps track of all values captured with repeated capturing groups, they all are accessible via `.captures(1)` here. You can test this feature with a [.NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5CS*%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%28%5CS%2B%29%29%7B1%2C5%7D&i=beef%20tomato%20chicken%20trump%20Madonna):[image]

Comment: Thank you Wiktor ! I did not understand 1) that I can capture within a non-cpaturing extension  '(?: )' 2) nor did I get the idea to make each caption optional by preceeding it with a ?

Comment: I added an additional question above :-D

Comment: Then use something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/RyQ8sE/1)., use `(?:\s+(\w+),?)?` instead of `(?:\s+(\S+))?`. Or even [`(?:\s+(\w+)[^\w\s]*)?`](https://regex101.com/r/RyQ8sE/2) to handle any punctuation.

Comment: You are the Robert Lewandowski of regex :-)

Comment: Regex is much easier than soccer :)

Answer (score 0):

You got the correct approach. However regex can't do what you're asking for. Each time your capturing group captures another pattern, the previous content is replaced. That is why your capturing group only returns the last pattern captured.
You can easily match n words, but you can't capture them separately without writting each capture group explicitly.

Comment: @Jan, I think `\G` won't precise the number of matches. Well, surely we can "trim" the resulting list.

Comment: It does not work... You still capture only one word per match.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: And how exactly am I supposed to provide an example of code for something that does not work ? A code that doesn't work either ?

Comment: @Gawil FYI I think you may have been replying to someone whose comment has since been deleted, so right now your very first comment makes it look like you are talking to yourself...

Comment: @Ajean: Indeed ^^ I was replying to Jan, who was saying something like "*of course it's possible !*"... I should really try to always use the @ thing ^^ However I will never understand people who delete their comments in the middle of a discussion...